# Facebook profile picture request i.e. "http://graph.facebook.com/me/picture"

Tags: facebook, request, profile, image, handlers

When I do a request for a profile picture, mine in this case I receive some kind of encoded string in my HttpResponseHandler.  The code below is the request for my profile picture.

```
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

client.get("http://graph.facebook.com/1206433/picture",  fbPictureHandler);
```

The code below is my handler to retrieve a response.  I get the response as a string, but I am not sure what to do with this response object.  I have tried converting to a byte array and writing to "file.jpg" this hasnt worked.  My main question is what do I do with this response object?

```
private static AsyncHttpResponseHandler fbPictureHandler = new AsyncHttpResponseHandler ()        
{
@Override
public void onStart() {
Log.d(TAG,"started picture handler");
}
@Override
public void onSuccess(String response) {
        //Not sure what to do here, have been unable to do anything with this Byte   //array
    byte[] imageBackground = response.getBytes();

    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
        Log.d(TAG, "unable to retrieve picture");
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Finished picture handler");
    }
};
```

This is the PrintString of the response object

```
11-29 19:42:12.640: D/Yatter Facebook(3551): ÿØÿà��JFIF������������ÿþ��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg     v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 95
```

ANy help is greatly appreciated and hopefully this can help others.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following request instead of the one that you are issuing

http://graph.facebook.com/1206433?fields=picture

This will return a JSON string to you in the following format which contains the original path to the profile image.

```
{
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/260615_1206433_140418666_q.jpg"
}
```

Parse this string to get the path of "picture" and use it in your code to get the picture.

---

Here is a sample request example

NOTE  : http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/260615_1206433_140418666_q.jpg is obtained by parsing the JSON string in the first step.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/260615_1206433_140418666_q.jpg");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

This will load the image to a picture box in a windows form application.

If you need anymore help let me know.

Comment: Great this actually helps, now I know how to get the actual redirect URL using a JSONObject, with the picture field.  Just to let you know though I am using this code to retrieve the bitmap  `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
      "http://graph.facebook.com/"+facebookId+"/picture?type=medium").getContent());`

Comment: I am retreiving each image using a AsyncTask by the way, thanks alot Robin.

Answer (score 0):

you can use *?redirect=false* follow '/picture' for get direct link

```
http://graph.facebook.com/+facebookid+/picture?redirect=false
```

and response contain url static link (json format)

```
{"data":{
    "url":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-frc1\/t1.0-1\/c126.33.409.409\/s50x50\/551571_4079894629426_190963543_n.jpg","is_silhouette":false}
}
```